# How to compare the two OrderIds in Google Wallet?

Tags: javascript, php, android-pay

I am implementing Google Wallet for Digital Goods in a website, using PHP and HTML/JavaScript. I have achieved a successful Wallet transaction in the sandbox setting. So far, so good.

Now, in order to ensure the purchase is a secure transaction, I want to check whether the orderId that comes back in the successHandler is equal to the orderId received via a POST from Google in my postback file on the server.

I know a reasonable bit about PHP, less so about Javascript. After having studied all Google Wallet entries in StackOverflow and after having read over and over again the Google Wallet Merchant Setup pages, I still cannot figure out the proper code to compare the orderId coming from the successHandler and the orderId from the postback file. It seems to me that the successHandler's orderId (which I am guessing can be written as `result.response.orderId` which I have seen in other StackOverflow answers) is defined in Javascript, while the one from the postback file (which I call here `postback-orderId`) is defined in PHP.

- How can you compare the two? One is a Javascript variable, the other a PHP variable.
- I guess the best place to compare these variables is in the successHandler function. But how do I get a PHP variable from the postback file (called `$orderId` in that file) into a Javascript function which is used in another file?

I show what I have so far as my PURCHASE file and what I have as my POSTBACK file.

PURCHASE FILE

```
<?php
include ('sessionstart.inc');
require_once 'generate_token.php';
echo "
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1'>
<title>Digital Goods Application</title>
<script src='https://sandbox.google.com/checkout/inapp/lib/buy.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    //Success handler
    var successHandler = function(result){
      if (result.reponse.orderId == postback-orderId) {
        if (window.console != undefined) {
          console.log('Purchase completed successfully.');
      }
     }
    }

    //Failure handler
    var failureHandler = function(result){
      if (window.console != undefined) {
        console.log('Purchase did not complete.');
      }
    }
    function purchase(jwt_value) {
    runDemoButton = document.getElementById('runDemoButton')
    google.payments.inapp.buy({
    'jwt': jwt_value,
    'success': successHandler,
    'failure': failureHandler
    });
    return false;
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <p>Buy 5 Search Credits to continue searching The Clock Register.</p><br />
    <button id='runDemoButton' value='buy' class='buttons' onclick='purchase(\"$jwtToken\");'><b>Buy</b></button>
</div>
</body>
</html>";
?>
```

POSTBACK FILE

```
<?php
include ('sessionstart.inc');
include_once ('JWT.php');
$encoded_jwt = $_POST['jwt'];
$decodedJWT = JWT::decode($encoded_jwt,"mySecretKey");
$orderId = $decodedJWT->response->orderId;

header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
echo $orderId;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: @EdSF: I set `$orderId` in the POST-back file into a SESSION as follows: `$_SESSION['orderid'] = $orderId;` However, when I check on the value of $_SESSION['orderid'] it is empty. I don't understand that as I can see that $orderId has a value (I emailed myself the value of $orderId from the POST-back file). You suggested to write $orderId into the database first. I agree that that should work (haven't tried it yet), but I am puzzled why I cannot write it into a SESSION variable which should be faster and less toing and froing with the database. Your suggestion helped me a lot further, though!

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that the rendering of your page (and the buy action) happen long before the postback is dispatched / received by your server, as such, you can not have the postback-orderID in your page. You will have to do the following:

1. Your postback url target file / script should log the data received on your server (in a file or database).
2. You will need to write another php file / script on your server that can retrieve data from the logs in 1 above and does the comparison to check whether the orderID in the successHandler has been logged.
3. The success handler will have to make a call to the script in 2 above with, at least, the orderID as a parameter. (do not worry about the ajax call, it is simply javascript)

This may seem convoluted and long but can be achieved in less than 20 lines of code (both php and javascript / ajax).

**EDIT**
1. Updated ***postback.php*** to include logging

```
<?php
 require_once 'JWT.php';

 $encoded_jwt = $_POST['jwt'];
 $decodedJWT  = JWT::decode($encoded_jwt, $sellerSecret);
 $orderId     = $decodedJWT->response->orderId;

 header("HTTP/1.0 200 OK");
 echo $orderId;

 $logfile = "logfile.txt";
 if (!file_exists($logfile)) {
    touch($logfile);
    chmod($logfile, 0777);
 }
 $orderIDS   = file($logfile); //reads file into array
 $orderIDS[] = $orderId; //append new orderID to array
 file_put_contents($logfile, $orderIDS); //save the new array to file
?>
```

**EDIT 2** 
 second script ***IDSearch.php*** to search for orderIds

```
<?php
$orderSearch = $_GET['orderID'];
$logfile     = "logfile.txt";
if (file_exists($logfile)) {
    $orderIDS = file($logfile); //reads file into array
    echo (in_array($orderSearch, $orderIDS)); // either true or false is returned
} else {
    echo 'Error';
}
?>
```

**EDIT 3**
Finally, amending your successhandler to call the ***IDSearch.php*** script

```
var successHandler = function (result) {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            if (window.console != undefined) {
                console.log(xmlhttp.responseText);
            }
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "IDSearch.php?orderID=" + result.reponse.orderId, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

PS. In the handler, make sure you have the absolute path to the web resource of IDSearch.php

Comment: Thanks very much for this explanation. I am trying to build now what you and EdSF have suggested. If I get stuck I hope I may show you what I have done and where I got stuck.

Comment: @user2187593 - I have updated the answer and given some code examples on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Am not a PHP developer so this is more "conceptual" than specific -

The overall idea is that you would *persist* the data you received from the (server side) `POST` from Google (aka "the PHP variable" you received at your `postback url`) somehow - e.g. a database.

You then have options on what to do next (to compare) -

- perhaps an ajax call in your *success handler* to your server (that obtains the persisted data to) verify/compare the *"javascript variable/orderId"* with the *"Php variable/orderId"*, before doing x
- perhaps redirect in your *success handler* and send the *"javascript orderId"* as some value (query string, POST data, etc.) to a target that does the verification/comparison same as above (from server/db), and then do x

So its about persisting the data for later verification.

Hth....

---

#### Update (above disclaimer applies) :)

> I set $orderId in the POST-back file into a SESSION as follows: $_SESSION['orderid'] = $orderId; However, when I check on the value of $_SESSION['orderid'] it is empty.

*If I understood correctly*, you're setting a `Session Variable` from Google's *server-side Postback* which means the request/session isn't "tied" to the browser/client. It was a server side POST - the browser, where the payment process is happening has no knowledge of it - it wasn't involved in the *postback* at all (the "client" in that case was some Google machine).

In other words, the browser has no "knowledge" of that (separate/server-side) "session", it either has no "sessionID" (cookie) nor one that would match (remember it was "some Google machine" that made the request when you set a session variable)

Hth....

Comment: You are absolutely correct. My idea to work with SESSIONs does not make any sense... Thank God, you are around to get me back on track.